# spring MVC application is not working when using <context:component-scan> and throws 404 error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations

MVC application is throwing 404 Error when using annotations component scan tag . The same is working fine with explicit xml bean injections. Please find below the respective code.

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>AbsSpringMVCProj</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

**spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

<mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.happy.hellocontroller.HelloController" />
 <!-- <bean id="HandlerMapping"  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping"/>  -->

    <!-- <context:component-scan base-package = "com.happy.hellocontroller.HelloController" /> -->

    <!-- <bean name="/welcome.html" class="com.happy.hellocontroller.HelloController" /> -->
   <!-- <bean name="/page2.html" class="com.happy.hellocontroller.HelloController" />
   <bean name="/greet/page2.html" class="com.happy.hellocontroller.HelloController" />   -->

 <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
 </bean>


</beans>
```

**HelloController.java**

```
package com.happy.hellocontroller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController;


/*
 * XML based
 * 
 *//*
public class HelloController extends AbstractController{

    @Override
    protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ModelAndView modelandView = new ModelAndView("HelloPage");
        modelandView.addObject("welcomeMsg","Hi, this is coming from HelloController class");


        return modelandView;
    }

}*/

/*
 * Annotation base
 * 
 *  
 */
@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping("/welcome")
    public ModelAndView helloAbs()
    {
        ModelAndView modelandView = new ModelAndView("HelloPage");
         modelandView.addObject("welcomeMsg","Annotation Based, this is coming from HelloController class");

         return modelandView;
    }
    @RequestMapping("/page2")
    public ModelAndView helloPage2()
    {
        ModelAndView modelandView = new ModelAndView("HelloPage");
         modelandView.addObject("welcomeMsg","Annotation Based, this is coming from HelloController-helloPage2 class");

         return modelandView;
    }
    @RequestMapping("/page3")
    public ModelAndView helloPage3()
    {
        ModelAndView modelandView = new ModelAndView("HelloPage");
         modelandView.addObject("welcomeMsg","Annotation Based, this is coming from HelloController-helloPage33 class");

         return modelandView;
    }

}
```

when trying to hit the url "http://localhost:8080/AbsSpringMVCProj/welcome.html" it says

> HTTP 404 , resource not found .

The same is working fine when the below block in **spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml**   is uncommented :-

```
<!-- <bean  id="HandlerMapping"  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping"/>  -->

    <!-- <context:component-scan base-package = "com.happy.hellocontroller.HelloController" /> -->

    <!-- <bean name="/welcome.html" class="com.happy.hellocontroller.HelloController" /> -->
   <!-- <bean name="/page2.html" class="com.happy.hellocontroller.HelloController" />
   <bean name="/greet/page2.html" class="com.happy.hellocontroller.HelloController" />   -->
```

Please help me understand :

1. what am I possibly am I doing wrong while using annotations ?
2. am I missing any settings for making the component-scan tag work and automatically take the @component and @RequetMapping tags ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to declare particular class name in your  `<context:component-scan ..>`.Just need to declare package level. According to your **spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml**, no need to declare **HelloController** class. Change your component-scan tag likes this

```
<context:component-scan base-package = "com.happy.hellocontroller" />
```

Comment: It's ok. I think you use spring 4x then personally I recommend annotation declaration instead of xml configuration.So think about it for future development.

Comment: Yeah sure . One more doubt here, hitting **http://localhost:8080/AbsSpringMVCProj/greet/welcome**

Comment: One more doubt - why does http://localhost:8080/AbsSpringMVCProj/welcome and http://localhost:8080/AbsSpringMVCProj/welcome.**html** works here? as I have mentioned only "/welcome"  in my @RequestMapping annotation .